# Definition of object oriented programming

Tags: oop, scripting, definition

Shouldn't it be called object oriented *scripting* when using scripting languages such as php, actionscript and so on? The definition of oop and oos would be the same but naming the use after what language you are using?

Comment: Despite my primary language (Python, but doesn't matter) being called a scripting language, and despite the fact I do occasionally write scripts in it, I'm **programming** in that language, so I'd say it qualifies as a **programming** language. Unless of course that word was redefined in the meantime?

Comment: I use PHP to make websites and webapps, and nothing else. Does that mean PHP is a webapping language? Oh dear. I must now go adjust my resume...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it shouldn't. The act of writing software for a computer (or anything else, I guess) is "programming". If you use a technology based on objects, it is object-oriented programming. Making a distinction serves no purpose.

Comment: It serves the purpose of allowing people -who aren't good enough to understand how to program well in a dynamically typed languages and require a prison of static typing to be able to generate working code (usually not that well) - to feel superior to people who are able to code well in both. </snob>

Answer (score 0):

Considering the fact that most so-called "scripting" languages these days that have OOP have significantly more reason to be called "programming" languages than "scripting" ones, no, it shouldn't.

The only languages I can legitimately call "scripting" (as in, can't be **easily** used for "real programming") is AWK or unix shell scripting (sh or csh or bash); or DOS batch file languages.

The reason those languages you thought of (Per/Python) are sometimes called "scripting" is not because you can't program in them, but because in those cases when you need to write a small script, they ARE better suited than other languages. Mostly due to their dynamic typing and system integration.

However, pretty much all of those languages (not sure about PHP) are just as "programming" as the languages considered "real programming" languages by people as misinformed as you are.

Please note that this answer specifically applies to Python and Perl - I don't know enough about ActionScript or PHP to know where they stand (PHP is likely to fall under "programming").

**Please note that it's more about the quality of the developer than particulars of the language.**

I've seen (and written) beautiful and complex OO systems in Perl.

I've also seen a horrifying collection of excrement that was unfortunately considered to be a C++ "program".